# Django inline forms cannot query, must be model instance

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make inline forms with class based views, i followed the instrunctions from [here](https://github.com/adandan01/mybook). The only change i've made was to give self.request.user instead of self.object to instance:

**models.py**

```
class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser)
    translate = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class ClientData(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ClientForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['user', ]


class ClientDataForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ClientData
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['client', ]


ClientFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Client, ClientData, form=ClientDataForm, extra=1)
```

**views.py**

```
class ClientView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Client
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('core:index')


class ClientDataView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'core/client_data.html'
    model = ClientData
    form_class = ClientDataForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('core:index')

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        profile = get_object_or_404(ClientData, client__user=self.request.user)
        return profile

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ClientDataView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['client_data'] = ClientFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.get_object())
        else:
            context['client_data'] = ClientFormSet(instance=self.get_object())
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        client_data = context['client_data']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()
            if client_data.is_valid():
                client_data.instance = self.object
        return super(ClientDataView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Whenever i try to enter the page i get:

```
ValueError: Cannot query "asd@gmail.com": Must be "Client" instance.
[13/Dec/2017 15:48:36] "GET /client-data/ HTTP/1.1" 500 143759
```

for this line:

```
context['client_data'] = ClientFormSet(instance=self.get_object())
```

Comment: Instantiating formsets in `get_context_data` is hacky. You might want to look at [django-extra-views](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views), which has a view for inline formsets.

Comment: have you used them? i know i've tryed once but didn't work out

Comment: No, I haven't used them before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `get_object` is returning a `ClientData` instance.

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    profile = get_object_or_404(ClientData, client__user=self.request.user)
    return profile
```

However, as the error suggests, the instance should be a `Client` instance, for example:

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Client, user=self.request.user)
    return profile
```

Or you can simply follow the one-to-one relation backwards:

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    return self.request.user.client
```

Comment: hi, now it's rendering the page, but following his example renders twice the same form, any ideea how to get both forms in template?

Comment: I can't help with that. I would avoid trying to add an inline formset to an `UpdateView`, it's pretty hacky. I would try django-extra-views or use a function based view.

Comment: well i am using extra views now, and again i'm getting the same form twice, i don't know why, can you help a second with this?

Comment: That's a separate problem from your original question, I can't help with that.